# SFTP from External vendor s3 bucket to my (company's) AWS s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Task**: Load 13TB (100s of files) from an external s3 bucket to company s3 bucket

**Given**: .pem and .ppk file, s3 hostname, username

**Done so far**: Able to view files via FileZilla/WinSCP using provided .pem/.ppk file, hostname and username

**Requirements**: Determine best way to load these hundreds of .gz files from an external vendor's s3 bucket to my company's s3 bucket, preserving the same structure. And then loading the same into snowflake from internal s3. Options being considered: AWS Snowball, python, Volume --> s3, python to load into snowflake from s3.

I am unsure how to proceed. Any input?

Comment: What does SFTP have to do with anything here? How about you give the native [`CopyObject`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) a shot?

Comment: Google is always a good place to start: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-large-transfer-between-buckets/. Stackoverflow is better for asking specific, technical questions

Comment: Firstly, do you have access to the data in the source bucket? How is that access being provided -- is it public, or have you been given AWS credentials, or perhaps they have added your IAM User/Role to their S3 bucket policy? What do you mean by "given .pem and .ppk file"? Who gave you these files and what are they associated with? Also "Given username" -- what is it the username for? Please Edit your Question to add these details.

Comment: Why move 13TB of files? Can't you have Snowflake read them from the vendor's bucket?

Answer (score 0):

If the vendor is willing to work with you and S3 is the final destination, I would ask if they could set replication to your bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html